# custom validator not working

Tags: c#

I have applied a custom validator ona textbox whose value is chnaged by a calendar. I have given a server side validation to check whether it is a past date or not. The validator is fired on click of submit button. The args.IsValid value is set to false, but still the code enters the click event of the submit button instead of showing the error message.
Please help.

```
aspx.cs file
protected void CustomValidatorIssueDate_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        string nowString = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        DateTime now = Convert.ToDateTime(nowString);
        DateTime issueDate = Convert.ToDateTime(args.Value);
        if (issueDate.CompareTo(now) > 0)
        {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
    }

aspx file

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxIssueDate" runat="server" Width="214px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxIssueDate" 
                        ErrorMessage="Issue Date cannot be past date" 
                        onservervalidate="CustomValidatorIssueDate_ServerValidate" 
                        ID="CustomValidatorIssueDate" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="True" ></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Comment: is it possible to provide any of the code that you are referring to?

Comment: Are you checking args.IsValid and doing something if it's not? Or are you expecting it to bypass the method if IsValid == false?

Comment: Please post the code you're talking about, the aspx of the validator control and the textbox would be useful

Comment: @Jamie  I am expecting it to bypass the onclick event of button if args.IsValid is set to false in customValidator method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your onclick event handler won't be bypassed simply by setting `IsValid` to `false`.

You'll need to do a check inside your event handler for IsValid.

```
if(Model.IsValid)
{
}
```

(or something similar to that).